# What is going on with the transformations?? SSGSS is not stronger then SS1?

Tags: dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-z

What is the significance of a SS.god.SS when brolly as a ss.berserk can make goku and vegeta struggle to keep up?

After all the idea behind the transformations is more power and strength per each new transformation.
As I continue to watch the show, I see during the initial transformation they are "stronger and more powerful" but then later once the character returns back into the transformation, all that has changed was the hair colour, I am now starting to think that a super sayian 1 is just as strong as a SSGodSS,  and goku only uses SSGSS because he likes his hair to look blue,

To prove my point Ill refer to a couple fights that leave me speechless 
1. Goku as a SS3 when up against Berus - Goku could even hit Berus infact a flick on the forehead knocked goku out.
- that shows the Power Level difference right there!!

2. Goku as a SS God (red hair) could not even fight Berus on earth because the shock of energy would destroy earth

   - this shows how much stronger a SSgod is compared to a regular sayain right?? Like a whole nother level!!!
3. Goku as a SSGodSS (blue hair) actually scared Berus as goku was able to match Berus"s level

   - GODLY!!!

With that being said, goku should have no problem as a super sayian blue fighting with brolly, who is one step past SS1 and under a SS2 level, - to me I cannot make sense of this??? Unless dB super is trying to say, brolly is stronger then Berus, ssgss goku and vegeta, and if that is the case, then what's the point of having a SS2, SS3, SSGod, SSGSS, or now Ultra Instinct which I know is not a real SS transformation?

I honestly expect as a SSGSS goku should struggle against real strong enemies, but up against a Lower class sayian transformation goku should be wiping the floor with them.

I like brolly and always have, but there is just no way, he should be able to even see gokus movements when is blue, along with Berus. So I feel like the God transformation is being so undercut it's not funny and is actually making me a bit upset with the series,

To add insult to injury, they gave brolly 3 movies, in which it didn't take the strength of a SSGodSS to defeat him! 3 normal ss took him on, plus some help with the Z fighters team to be live punching bags.

I'm confident that a SSblueSS Kamehameha point blank range at brollys face should leave brolly headless

Comment: This is a pretty loaded or otherwise too broadly scoped question. Please edit your question narrow down the scope. To be better and more adequately answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty elaborate question, however , I will try to break down the answer to every sub-question in points.

- Firstly,  transformations are multipliers. A stronger transformation, multiplies Goku's power to a higher level. The Super Saiyan God transformation, is a higher multiplier than even the Super Saiyan 3 transformation which is very obvious in the Battle of Gods arc. Hence, Super Saiyan 1 is not stronger than Super Saiyan God. However, you have to remember, Base Goku can get substantially stronger. Current Base Goku, is stronger than Super Saiyan 3  Goku from the Buu Saga(Based on Base Vegeta vs SSJ3 Gotenks fight// Goku and Vegeta are relative in strength). So technically, it is possible for Super Saiyan Goku in the future, to be stronger than Super Saiyan God Goku from the past.
- Beerus was excited about getting an opportunity to fight the Super Saiyan God and was merely toying around. He isn't afraid of Super Saiyan Blue. In the manga, Mastered Super Saiyan Blue Vegeta is taken out by Beerus with a **single shot**. Beerus is one of the **strongest God of destruction** across the multiverse. This was established in the fight between all the Gods of destruction in the manga.
- Before I get into Broly, I would like to talk about **Frieza**.  He was weaker than **Namek Saga Goku who is weaker than Buu Saga Goten and Trunks**. However, when he returned in the ROF saga, he was **stronger** than Super Saiyan Blue Goku and only lost because of the Stamina drain issue.  Now if one were to look at your argument, where these **powerful transformations aren't to be rivaled** , Freiza ideally would have been one shot by Base Goku and the entire ROF arc/ Movie would've been over in 5 minutes.
- It is very important to note that Broly is being introduced as **a new character**. The Broly from the previous 2 movies isn't canon. This character for this Broly is being written by Toriyama himself. Hence, you shouldn't classify Broly's transformation as a lower transformation until you actually see the movie.
- Broly is the antagonist for the new Dragon Ball movie. Based on your logic, if the **main antagonist is weaker than a protagonist** in a Dragon Ball Series, there would be **no plot, no fights and basically no content.** If you want a show where the protagonist one shots every antagonist and the story progresses, I recommend you watch *"One Punch Man"*.

The Dragon Ball Series revolves around Goku and the rest of the Z fighters. Hence, we get to see these fighters become stronger and progress in power and achieve certain milestones. We do not see the same with regard to the antagonists. We have no idea how Jiren grew so strong by his own and was able to rival/surpass a God of Destruction. We also don't know how Toppo grew substantially strong enough to be chosen as a candidate to become a God of Destruction. We just have to accept it as some characters are always going to be a lot stronger than what we think, while some are going to be weaker than what we think based on what the plot dictates.

If you watch the trailer, Vegeta and Goku do not recognize Broly. Hence, he is being introduced as a new character. Vegeta also mentioned that he was growing stronger during the course of battle. Maybe he can be compared to Goku Black(who was relative to SSJ2 Goku at the start and grew stronger than SSJB Goku easily)? I personally would have a problem only if Broly were to rival or be superior to Mastered Ultra Instinct Goku, considering that is a level above the Gods. I don't see why Broly shouldn't Surpass Super Saiyan Blue considering the fact that there have been characters who have surpassed the same.

Comment: thank you for your response, I was hoping for another antagonist that could match gokus ssgss power similar to jiren to avoid a one punch show. I accept that there are stronger villains. If brolly is stronger the UI, ill be just as disappointed, this means that base brolly is stronger then current base goku after the tournament of power, how else could brolly match ssb power when using a lesser multiplier then ssgss transformation? I think your right comparing brolly to goku black in terms of power increase. I did realize they are re-introducing brolly, but the movies did a great job on him bf

Comment: Base Broly might even end up being stronger than Super Saiyan Goku considering the fact that we see him fighting Super Saiyan Vegeta in the trailer whose power is relative to that of Goku.

Comment: Yeah that does make a lot of sense, I hope they give brolly some history to eleberate why he got as strong as he did. I understand brolly is a "gifted" sayain but there would have had to be struggles to obtain his current level he achieved I would amagine. - will stay tuned to the movie I know it will be good!!